# Giving resources to a cli user via gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, command-line-interface

I am building a command line interface in Node.js using commander (and a bunch of other tools). So far, everything has been going well, but I've run into a problem that I'm not sure of an elegant way to solve.

My cli helps generate projects for my company (we have a specific folder structure that this will enforce. Our company has a shared resource folder, we'll call it foo. So, I'd like to ship foo with the cli.

What I want to happen is they press `cli new foobar` which should generate the following folder structure.

```
foobar -
    | - foobar-ui
    |    - foo
    | - etc...
```

Cli folder structure:

```
bar-cli -
    | - generation
    |    - js files
    | - foo
```

My question is how to get foo from my cli folder space to the built output of the folder structure.

My first instinct was to use Gulp, as that's really what it was made for, but short of using an absolute location for where my cli could be installed, I'm not sure how to give gulp foo as a src.

Anyone have any ideas? (Non gulp answers will be accepted, but I thought it might be a good jumping off point).

And because I know the drill, here is roughly what I've tried:

```
program
  .command('new [projectName]')
  .description('...')
  .action(() => {
    // Makes folder structure
  }).then(() => {
    return gulp.src('./foo/*')
            .gulp.dest('./foobar/foobar-ui/foo/')
  });
```

Comment: do you want relative patch from bar-cli: `../foobar/foobar-ui/foo/`? Both `foo` folders are same?(maybe symlink)

Comment: @und3rdg Well, the bar-cli should be under `usr/local/bin` in theory, but any call to the program will be relative to the directory they called the cli from. I want to make a copy of the foo folder, because I don't want them to edit the cli' s version.